# Gmail API on Laravel project with several email

Tags: laravel, gmail-api

For a project I'm trying to build on Laravel, my goal is to be able to create a quick prototype on which I would be able to connect 3 of my gmail accounts. Goal is to have an overview of all messages, and be able to send some through one platform.

I first took at look at Socialite API on Laravel, problem is that it's just to connect to Google and not to communicate with the Gmail API.
I found an online tutorial to be able to fetch Gmail contacts : https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel/

Problem is that I'm not with there is a Laravel package to authorize several accounts of the same providers to be connected at the same time ?

Didn't find any information online, has someone already faced this problem ?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.7.

Comment: It's very hard to understand the line 'Problem is that I'm not with there is a Laravel package to authorize several accounts of the same providers to be connected at the same time ?' If you could try to explain the meaning of this line by using a different sentence it will be easier for other users to understand the problem.